# "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0

Tags: software-center

This problem appears in various ways eg. a simple lsb_release command. It seems ubuntu cannot determine the version.

LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 when I run locale on the command line so this does not fix the problem.

Here's the output...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 59, in main
    distinfo = lsb_release.get_distro_information()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 394, in get_distro_information
    lsbinfo = get_os_release()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 366, in get_os_release
    for line in os_release_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Driving me nuts. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a `LSB_OS_RELEASE` variable in your environment (ex. `printenv | grep LSB`)? What is the output of `xxd -l 8 /usr/lib/os-release` ?

Comment: Thanks steeldriver.

Output `printenv` | grep LSB is nothing

Output `xxd -l 8 /usr/lib/os-release` is `00000000: 5052 4554 5459 5f4e                      PRETTY_N`

Comment: OK thanks, so I'm stumped - I can reproduce exactly this error by doing `printf '\x99' > somefile` and then running `LSB_OS_RELEASE=./somefile lsb_release -a` so everything is pointing to a spurious byte at the start of that file.

Comment: Sorry, which file?

Comment: ... `./somefile` is an arbitrary new file in the current directory, it's just a way of debugging without modifying the *actual* `/usr/lib/os-release` file